# Prevent a video to open in the apple video player

Tags: html, ios, video, safari, mobile-safari

On iPhones when playing a video in safari the standard is that apple opens a fullscreen video player and plays the video there like here:

[image]

In my case i dont want that, i just want to let the video play in the html in safari without opening the videoplayer:

[image]

How do you prevent a video to open in the apple standard video player?
Is it possible?

This is the video:

```
<video id="video-m-1" class="video" preload="none" poster="dist/Images/Weltkugel_Initial_Mobile_v2.png">
                <source src="dist/Videos/Kugel-Ganz-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has finally enabled the `playsinline` attribute on iOS 10, so this will work:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>
```

the video will not be opened in the video player, it will lay inline in the html

Comment: What about <iframes>  same deal?